# Quem devem ser nossos moderadores?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, comunidade, big-7, moderação

Esta é mais uma das [7 perguntas que toda nova comunidade deve fazer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) antes de se graduar.

Em alguns dias ou semanas, esta comunidade vai receber alguns moderadores provisórios para ajudar este site começar antes das eleições no final do beta. Por favor, leia (em inglês): [Moderadores Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Por favor, sugira alguns membros desta comunidade que você acha que seriam excelentes moderadores (auto indicações são bem-vindas).

Aqui estão algumas diretrizes básicas:

- Cada candidatura deve ser uma resposta em separado. Vincular o nome para o perfil do usuário (o principal e meta), para que possamos ver a sua atividade.
- O candidato deverá indicar a sua aceitação, editando a resposta, acrescentando que aceita a indicação. Opcionalmente pode escrever algo sobre si mesmo.
- Auto indicações são bem-vindas, e até mesmo incentivada. A maioria dos sites não tiveram tempo suficiente para muitos usuários se destacarem. Auto indicação é simplesmente uma maneira de dizer: "Eu estou interessado. Que o meu registro fale por si". Links para outras atividades podem ser úteis:  participação no Area 51, a participação em outros sites, blogs ou posts anunciando o site, etc.
- O que estamos procurando em um moderador...

Estamos buscando os membros que estão profundamente envolvidos no desenvolvimento da comunidade, os membros que:

- Tenham uma reputação razoavelmente grande para indicar a participação consistente ativa.
- Mostrar interesse em atividades de construção da comunidade em seu meta.
- Liderar pelo exemplo, demonstrando paciência e respeito pelos seus companheiros e membros da comunidade em tudo o que escrevem.
- Expor essas características intangíveis discutidas em [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Pontos de bônus para:

- Membros com a participação em ambos meta e no site principal (isto é, interesse tanto na construção da comunidade e experiência na área).
- Participação no Area 51, referências em redes sociais, ou blogs sobre o site.
- Os membros que já demonstraram interesse ou capacidade de promover a sua comunidade.

Comment: Não indiquei outros porque não sei se aceitariam. Preferi ir nos mais seguros.

Comment: De certa forma está sendo emocionante participar da formação e "nascimento" de um site assim, embora eu mesmo não sirva de forma alguma como moderador, principalmente porque tenho tendência a ser muito complacente. Gostei muito das indicações. Agora é esperar a hora do "*and the oscar goes to...*"

Comment: @utluiz agora já sabemos para quem foi. E sabemos como a SE me odeia :) Preferiram deixar um moderador a menos do que o normal e deixar algumas *tags* onde tenho expertise sem alguém para moderador do que me escolher.

Comment: @bigown é difícil entender o que uma pessoa "realmente" quis dizer ao ler um texto, grande parte da conversa se dá pela entonação da voz, mas lendo seu texto eu imagino que você possa de fato estar chateado com a decisão tomada hoje pois acredito que a moderação era algo que você almejava muito, não sei se te consola (nem se vc precisa) mas eu diria que em uma eventual eleição você com ctz seria um dos escolhidos, e provavelmente um dos mais votados. Todos devemos muito a você, e se eventualmente sua afirmação que a SE te odeia for verdadeira, saiba que o SOPT te ama :)

Comment: @Math Obrigado pelas palavras, eu nem mereço. E não falo por humildade não. Claro que eu fico chateado, mas já sabia que não seria escolhido. Eu ficaria menos chateado se alguém melhor que eu fosse escolhido para a 3a. posição. E tem pessoas para isto. Ainda bem que pelo menos as duas escolhidas foram excelentes escolhas. Eu não sei se vou me candidatar, afinal não sei quanto tempo eu duraria. Digamos que a decisão que não me incluiu foi o que menos me chateou hoje. Isto era esperado, é consistente com a postura já demonstrada. Problema maior é quando tem dois pesos e duas medidas.

Comment: @bigown eu falei que vc ia ser o mais votado! :D

Comment: @Math é, acertou :D eu fiz umas contas, mas nem vou falar nada, agora sou "peace &love lil'bigown" :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Indico o [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) ([meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto)) pelo seu entusiasmo, excelentes posts no meta, e sua experiência nos sites da rede. Ele já demonstrou interesse pelo site antes mesmo dele ter nascido e desde o primeiro momento sua atividade geral não só é imensa, mas extremamente qualitativa. Sabe escrever muito bem e entende dos assuntos que mais são perguntados aqui.

---

Eu aceito a indicação – se forem mesmo três vagas; senão, deixo a vaga para o bigown.

#### Eu, e minha relação com o Stack Overflow

Sou autodidata em programação. Comecei com uns 12 ou 13 anos, com Visual Basic 2, e nunca mais parei. Quando me formei, na área de Humanas (!), percebi que queria mesmo era trabalhar com programação, então fui fazer isso. Eu gosto de aprender, e tenho facilidade de aplicar na prática o que aprendo, então corri atrás do conhecimento e comecei a trabalhar com sistemas baseados na web, numa época em que isso ainda não era tão comum no Brasil. Até hoje meu foco é a web, mas meu gosto pessoal e a natureza do meu trabalho exigem que eu viva ligado em todo tipo de tecnologia.

Tenho uma característica que às vezes é um defeito, e outras é uma qualidade: sou obsessivo e perfeccionista. Às vezes fico atormentado porque *não sei* algo, e isso acaba me levando a procurar saber mais. Como não tenho educação formal na área de computação, acontece com uma certa frequência. Eu descobri o Stack Overflow por causa disso. Encontrei no site não apenas explicações excelentes, mas principalmente um "caldo de conhecimentos" que mora nas entrelinhas do conteúdo. Aprendi novos métodos para resolver problemas. Aprendi a encontrar as melhores referências. Aprendi a aprender melhor. Num dado momento percebi que tentar escrever *respostas* no site era uma ótima ferramenta para aprender mais, e fiz isso – adivinhem – obsessivamente.

Quando eu soube da proposta do site na Area 51, imediatamente me interessei. Quem não sabe inglês o suficiente para usar o site com desenvoltura merece um equivalente em português. Merece um lugar onde exista conteúdo trabalhado, organizado e centralizado. Conteúdo que possa gerar caldo de conhecimento, e que permita a mais gente aprender como eu tenho aprendido. Eu estou aqui porque acredito nisso.

#### Moderação comunitária

Desde que o site abriu, tenho dedicado bastante tempo a ele, e procurado colaborar tanto com respostas (mais do que com perguntas, não sou de perguntar muito), quanto ajudando a definir as diretrizes de funcionamento do site, ajudando a editar e organizar os conteúdos, e ajudando novos usuários a utilizar a plataforma. Eu gosto de fazer isso, que é chamado de [*community moderation*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160960) e no fundo é boa parte do trabalho dos moderadores, considerados grandes faxineiros (o diamante é uma espécie de super vassoura). O que os moderadores fazem a mais é analisar o que os outros usuários dizem em sinalizações/flags, e tomar uma decisão final sobre aquilo que eles não podem fazer sozinhos.

Nunca fui moderador em nenhum outro site da rede (ou fora dela), mas conheço bem como funciona o Stack Overflow em inglês, e as ferramentas da rede Stack Exchange em geral. [Participei intensivamente do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825789/bfavaretto) durante mais de dois anos, e frequento assiduamente o "metão" para me atualizar sobre as discussões sobre o site e a rede. Minha participação lá é [relativamente modesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167534/bfavaretto), mas me orgulho muito de ter proposto um [faq sobre diretrizes de análise de posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing).

#### Se eu for um moderador

Essa experiência prévia vale alguma coisa, mas se eu for moderador não pretendo agir aqui como ajo no SO. Aqui, as regras são outras, e muitas delas ainda estão sendo definidas. No início isso me deixou um pouco perdido, mas depois acabei achando interessante, e aprendi a agir de acordo – por exemplo, segurando meus votos para fechar e votos contrários, e procurando usar mais os comentários para orientar os usuários.

Se eu for moderador, vou aplicar as regras definidas (e continuar participando da definição dessas regras). Se alguém achar injusta a aplicação ou a natureza das regras, estou disposto a discuti-las. E se alguém achar que errei no meu julgamento (e eu *vou* errar, é inevitável), posso rever minhas decisões, se a outra parte tiver bons argumentos. Quem frequenta o chat e o meta sabe que estou aberto a discussões.

Também estou disposto a arcar com o peso de ser moderador: abrir mão da minha opinião pessoal em muitos casos, e aguentar o tranco de tomar decisões difíceis em relação a perguntas, respostas e usuários. E abrir mão de meu tempo em prol do site. Hoje, se eu quiser sumir do site por um mês, eu posso. Sendo moderador, não posso. Tudo bem, ossos do ofício.

---

Não sirvo para falar de mim mesmo. Gasto muito tempo para escrever muito pouco. Mas se tiverem perguntas, vocês sabem onde me achar!

Answer (score 28):

Indico o [bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown) ([meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown)), por motivos que já devem ser óbvios para quem tem acompanhado o site. Ele criou a proposta original do site na Area 51, e tem dedicado um tempo absurdamente grande ao site e ao meta desde a abertura do beta privado, há quase dois meses. Sem ele o site certamente não estaria organizado como está hoje, e não teríamos tanto conteúdo importante no meta. E como ainda há muito o que melhorar, o bigown sem dúvida *precisa* das ferramentas de moderador para fazer um trabalho ainda melhor. O bigown tem sabido ouvir e respeitar opiniões e sugestões de outros membros da comunidade, e certamente continuará agindo assim.

---

#### Minhas credenciais

Tenho uma experiência razoável na rede, participando de sites diferentes, já **tendo sido moderador no [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)** na fase mais difícil quando o site passava por uma crise de identidade.

Além de ter criado a proposta e acompanhado todo processo até chegarmos aqui, fui o que mais [indicou usuários qualificados](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539?phase=commitment&committers=totalreputation#tab-top) para o *commit* na proposta.

**Estou aqui no site virtualmente 24X7**, faço tudo o que eu posso mesmo me prejudicando pessoalmente, mas acho que nós que falamos português merecemos algo que só o Stack Oveflow em Português pode oferecer. Costumo ter pelo menos 3 páginas abertas 24 horas por dia, o site principal, o meta e o chat. Estou lá no chat para ajudar quem precise com o funcionamento do site.

Tenho participado fortemente e vou continuar assim enquanto eu puder. Não sou perfeito, eu erro em alguns pontos, mas estou sempre querendo melhorar. Posso revisar minhas posições conforme recebo feedback.

Gosto de uma **gama de tecnologias bastante extensa**.  Não sou especialista em todas, mas tenho boa noção de muita coisa. Tenho o fundamento que ajuda a entender até o que ainda não conheço.

Estou completando exatos **30 anos de profissão**, tendo passado por todas evoluções desde os anos 80, quando escovávamos bits.

Nem preciso dizer que já conheço o [Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

#### Como pretendo trabalhar

- Vou continuar muito ativo em comentar e editar ([minhas atividades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown?tab=activity)).
- Sei que precisarei ser mais seletivo em algumas ações.
- Em alguns casos minha palavra será a última (ou quase) e precisarei esperar a comunidade agir e só entrar quando a situação pedir urgência ou quando a comunidade falha.
- Precisarei ser um pouco mais *hands off* em questões definitivas.
- Procurarei consenso na comunidade.
- Vou dar minha opinião, sei que ela terá peso, mas **não** estou aqui para determinar pela comunidade o que ela deva fazer.
- Devo orientar, sim, quando sentir que algo não está em um bom caminho. Entendo que moderação envolve alguma liderança.
- Vou deixar meu gosto pessoal de lado. Já estou agindo algumas vezes contra minha vontade pessoal. Ainda não temos muitas diretrizes claras aqui, é normal, por isso vou ter que me adaptar conforme vamos achando nosso caminho. Já fiz adaptações na primeira semana do beta público.
- Nem sempre poderei tomar a decisão mais popular, mas tentarei achar uma solução que seja boa para todo mundo e que não desvirtue o site, sempre que for necessário.
- Não serei moderador isolado, sempre contarei com o apoio de outros moderadores para evitar erros (mesmo que eles sempre possam ser revertidos).

#### Conclusão

Tenho um enorme interesse em fazer deste site um dos maiores sucessos da rede SE. E acho que posso contribuir para alcançar esse objetivo se puder agir mais ativamente. Acredito que um Stack Overflow em Português não será apenas útil para os programadores. Pelo menos no Brasil (não posso falar com propriedade sobre o cenário em outros países) ele será revolucionário. Só depende de nós.

Estamos aqui para aprender, e isso é o que mais precisamos incentivar. Entendo que precisamos eliminar o ruído que afasta os especialistas que nos ajudam aprender.

Estou disponível para perguntas aqui ou [no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Answer (score 19):

Indico o [Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/223/zuul) ([meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/223/zuul)) pelo seu entusiasmo, excelentes posts no meta, e sua experiência nos sites da rede. Ele já demonstrou interesse pelo site antes mesmo dele ter nascido e desde o primeiro momento sua atividade geral não só é imensa, mas extremamente qualitativa. Está em fuso horário diferente e agrega multiculturalismo ao site que não é só para brasileiros.

---

Eu aceito a indicação para moderação, sob a ressalva de que sendo o menos qualificado, a minha vinculação virá sempre após os dois utilizadores que tem feito um excelente trabalho até ao momento neste campo, o @bigown e o @bfavaretto.

## Um pouco sobre mim

Trabalho na área de desenvolvimento de software à já 18 anos e tenho vindo a expandir a minha área de conhecimentos desde então.
Actualmente estou mais ligado ao desenvolvimento de soluções que tem como base a Internet, em termos claros, sou um WebDev, com particular uso regular de:

[php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [css3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3), [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [html5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), [bash](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) entre outros derivados.

Sou designer à já 14 anos, uma área que sempre me fascinou, tendo começado por design de embalagens, movido para design de entidade e nos últimos anos WebDesign. Esta paixão pelo design tem motivado a constante aprendizagem de novas técnicas com recurso a CSS/jQuery e aperfeiçoamento das técnicas já implementadas (Sou um forte adepto do [refactoring](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refatora%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

Aliado a tudo isto, sou aquilo a que se pode chamar de perfeccionista, ou seja, demoro *o meu tempo* a fazer as coisas porque não gosto de "virgulas fora do sitio".

Tenho vindo a gerir equipes de programadores à alguns anos o que de certa forma tem motivado a evolução da minha capacidade de análise e discernimento de problemas. Também tem sido bom para me facultar com técnicas que me permitem manter *on-topic*.

## Eu na SE

Conheci a [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/) à cerca de 4 anos, tendo feito o meu registo pouco depois. Desde então tenho vindo a participar em vários web-sites da rede, tentando ajudar no que posso.

Não sou muito de perguntas, salvo este novo site [SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) onde efectivamente a presença de perguntas é um dos factores indispensáveis para que o site se gradue. Também recebo motivação extra pela possibilidade de documentar na minha língua e/ou partilhar o que tenho vindo a aprender ao longo deste anos.

Estive activo no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) e no [METÃO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), mantenho alguma participação em outros sites como é o caso do [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Neste momento a minha atenção recai integralmente sobre o SOPT pois tal foi o meu compromisso na [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese).

## Compromisso

Quando tive conhecimento do web-site SOPT, fiquei fascinado com a ideia, que não só propunha trazer para a minha língua um site de perguntas e repostas na área onde trabalho, como também fugir daquilo que por vezes é o *monstro* do SOEN.

O meu compromisso na Area 51 em Jul 19 '12 at 3:27 foi:

> "I'm Portuguese, I find relevant that user's less comfortable with English get an opportunity to contribute. I'll be every day given my best to help."

em Português:

> Eu sou Português e acho relevante que utilizadores menos confortáveis com a língua Inglesa tenham oportunidade de contribuir. Eu vou estar todos os dias dado o meu melhor para ajudar.

Assim o tenho feito, todos os dias desde que recebi o email a dar conta que o site estava em beta Privado.

## Moderação

Moderador ou não moderador, tenho tentado sempre assumir um papel de "auxiliar", aprimorando a formatação de perguntas, respostas e conteúdos das wiki de tags. Gosto de ler todos os comentários e filtrar o que é ou não é útil/construtivo para o tópico.

Sempre gostei de ajudar outros utilizadores, chegando até a [complementar a resposta deles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3611/223) com código de exemplo, links para documentação.

Não sou muito ligado à questão da reputação, penso que em primeiro está o espírito de equipa, e faço o que posso por ser diplomata e evitar confrontos. Obviamente que como qualquer um, gosto de ver a minha REP a crescer e estou sempre atento à possibilidade de deixar uma pergunta ou resposta.

Aceito muito bem o que é decidido pela comunidade, mas sou muito rigoroso e exigente no cumprimento das regras. Acho que para um site saudável as regras do mesmo devem ser decididas por todos os utilizadores, mas após uma decisão, o cumprimentos das mesmas é importante.

A minha participação aqui no META e sempre no sentido de expor a minha opinião e contribuir para a definição do web-site.

## Como Moderador

Se vier a ficar como moderador, podem contar com aquilo que já tenho feito, ou seja:

- Ajudar a manter o site saudável;
- Participar nas tomadas de decisões;
- Auxiliar na resolução de problemas;
- Melhorar perguntas com vista a um tópico saudável;
- Melhorar respostas trazendo às mesmas toda a informação relevante;
- Participar do [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para auxiliar no que for possível.

Farei os possíveis para ser o mais diplomata possível na revisão de Flags ou outros assuntos que careçam especial atenção por parte de um moderador, sempre em diálogo com os demais para um consenso antes da tomada de decisão.

A minha disponibilidade varia, como a de qualquer um que tenha um trabalho, mas dado estar em frente ao computador +/- 16horas por dia, tenho a possibilidade de estar atento a grande parte do dia.

O meu animo com este novo site e o constante entusiasmo em acompanhar o seu crescimento de forma saudável são de facto as duas mais valias que posso manifestar a meu favor.

<sup>**Notas:**

O texto em cima é um trabalho-em-progresso, não é o meu forte falar sobre mim. :)

Para facilitar, sugiro que qualquer pergunta sobre a minha aceitação da proposta para potencial moderador seja colocada como comentário nesta resposta. De qualquer forma, podem encontrar-me no chat com um @Zuul.</sup>