# Como saber se um candidato foi indicado ou auto indicado?

Tags: suporte, eleição

Já temos dois candidatos na comunidade para o cargo de moderador, e para ajudar na minha análise gostaria de saber se eles são uma indicação ou se ele são auto indicados.

Talvez para alguns isso não significa nada, mas sem dúvida um candidato indicado pode sair na frente nas eleições em detrimento de um candidato auto indicado e que não tem inicialmente muito apoio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Todos se auto indicaram.

A indicação indireta, quando ocorre, é para a escolha de moderadores pro tempore (provisórios) enquanto o site está em fase beta. Essa fase entretanto já ficou para trás e a partir de agora todas as eleições contarão com candidatos que se auto indicam.

No caso do SOPT chegamos a fazer as indicações indiretas e diretas para os moderadores da fase beta, através dessa publicação: [Quem devem ser nossos moderadores?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/713/3117). Mas a SE tinha preparado algo diferente a nós e as coisas saíram um pouco diferente do que a rede estava acostumada a fazer e além de demorar mais do que o habitual as indicações diretas ou indiretas não foram decisórias para a escolha dos moderadores.

Comment: Essa palavra "indicação" não é legal, parece que as pessoas são indicadas pelas outras. Não sei se *nomination* também tem esse problema no original. Poderíamos usar "candidatura" no lugar, ficaria bem claro.

Comment: @bfavaretto está coberto de razão, inclusive no termo que sugeriu, "candidatura", me parece que representa melhor essa etapa.

Comment: Também concordo com candidatura, eu mesmo fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu concordo plenamente, mas quando comecei a revisar as traduções de eleição, "indicação" já estava em vários lugares. Não valia a pena o retrabalho, considerando o corpo de coisas que ainda deviam ser traduzidas. Nós podemos organizar um mutirão depois dessa eleição e rever isso, com certeza.