# Eleições para Moderador 2016 - Questionário

Tags: debate, eleição

Essa é a sessão de perguntas e respostas para os candidatos à moderador do Stack Overflow em Português. As perguntas enviadas [na última quinta-feira](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5201/12) estão listadas aqui, para que os candidatos possam respondê-las. Estão no questionário as 6 perguntas enviadas mais 4 perguntas-padrão.

Os candidatos devem responder esse post, listando cada pergunta do questionário e a sua resposta. Para ajudar, as perguntas estão pré-formatadas como citações e com espaço entre elas, para sua resposta. Basta copiar tudo [depois da linha divisória](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/eee320d3-5c40-4d75-ab0a-803d18931a16/view-source). Lembrem-se também de colocar seu nome no **topo** do seu post, para que todo mundo possa saber quem é *antes* de ler tudo que você escreveu.

Depois que todos responderem, esse tópico será um registro das ideias e propostas de cada candidato e vai aparecer na perfil de cada um na página da eleição.

Boa sorte!

---

> 1. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?
> 2. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?
> 3. É fato conhecido que um moderador agrega tarefas adicionais ao seu uso normal do Stack Overflow. Duas possíveis consequências são:
>
>    1. Diminuição no tempo despendido em perguntas e respostas para dar conta das tarefas de moderador.
>    2. Aumento do tempo total despendido no site, com subsequente desgaste e diminuição geral na participação do site.
>
>    O que você acha mais provável de acontecer com você, por quê e como você pretende lidar com isto?
> 4. Porque é que você se candidatou a moderador?
> 5. Qual é o conjunto de tags que você visita com mais frequência e quais os tipos de perguntas que você está mais propenso e capacitado a responder?
> 6. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>      <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>
> 7. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?
> 8. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?
> 9. Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?
> 10. Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?

Comment: Parece-me que esse depois de todos responderem será só após a eleição ;)

Comment: Clarificando #3.2 (minha pergunta): é comum para vários moderadores da rede aumentar a participação após a eleição por algum período, porém algum dia eles acabam se desgastando e diminuindo a participação. É algo que pode ser psicológico ou causado por fatores internos e externos (prioridades vão mudando ao longo, mudança de emprego, etc.). A questão psicológica é explicada porque cada um tem um balanço natural no empenho que coloca em certa atividade. A partir do momento em que você se força acima desse limite, o desgaste é inevitável, sem contar o fim da empolgação inicial.

Comment: @Gabe isso ainda vai para o ar não? Ou fica para o ano que vem? ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Como assim?

Comment: "Depois que todos responderem, esse tópico será um registro das ideias e propostas de cada candidato e vai aparecer na perfil de cada um na página da eleição."

Comment: @JorgeB. É um erro de tradução. O sentido original é que o link pro questionário vai aparecer na [página da eleição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/2)

Comment: Bom ver que os verdadeiros candidatos interessados no cargo e no comprometimento com a comunidade e com a responsabilidade de se tornarem um moderador tiverem o compromisso de responder a este questionário, assim podemos ver, e analisar o quão cada candidato está verdadeiramente participativo e disposto a responder as perguntas da comunidade.

Answer (score 19):

## bigown

> 1. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

A primeira atitude é evitar que o problema escale, tentando conter a situação o quanto antes para não piorar, por exemplo já apagando um comentário ofensivo, mas justificando a razão para o usuário não achar que foi censura "gratuita". Feedback é importante para obter alguma solução definitiva.

Num caso contínuo, alertar o usuário (preferencialmente em particular) mostrando que tal comportamento está criando alguma complicação. Se for mais grave e a pessoa não aceita a "sugestão", provavelmente é caso de conversa com outros moderadores. Esse tipo de coisa não dá para decidir sozinho. É raro mas grave, portanto merece a atenção de todos que são ativos na moderação.

Reincidência geralmente merece advertência formal (com mecanismo próprio da rede) e até suspensão ou banimento. É claro que já devem existir "regras" que regem isso. Não sou eu quem vai inventar sozinho o que fazer. Se eu achar que o roteiro atual não funciona, proponho mudanças.

O importante é entender que ninguém está acima da "lei". Um usuário tem que respeitar a comunidade, não pode fazer o que bem entende. A maioria acaba se adequando, uns poucos acabam indo embora (o tipo de perda que, se inevitável, é ganho).

Um moderador tem que agir, mesmo que em alguns momentos vá desagradar alguém. A função principal do moderador é moderar, e não agradar usuários de todo tipo. Geralmente há solução inteligente e que não seja radical demais.

> 2. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Minha experiência como [moderador no Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/311/389) era de discutir quando havia discordância. Na prática raramente ocorria. Em geral um moderador respeita a decisão do outro. Obviamente fica mais fácil quando não há moderadores autoritários no time e que colocam sua vontade pessoal ou de uma "panela" acima dos interesses dos usuários como um todo.

Sempre tem o "depende". Em muitos casos, ao ver um moderador fazer diferente do que eu faria, eu simplesmente aceitaria a decisão (digamos que isso é o *default*). Não dá para ficar discutindo tudo. Mas se for algo fundamental e não conseguisse convencer o colega do contrário, uma possíbilidade seria levar o assunto para a comunidade debater. Para isso existe o Meta. Pelo que vejo hoje no SOpt, é improvável que isso seja necessário, e é sempre preferencial acreditar no trabalho do colega onde possível. No passado vi ações mais autoritárias, mas a moderação está andando melhor agora.

Na improvável hipótese de desacordos se tornarem regra, um debate interno entre os moderadores precisaria ocorrer.

A pergunta é importante, e em alguns pontos eu poderia ter um ângulo um pouco diferente de atuação, mas sempre em consonância com a comunidade.

> 3. É fato conhecido que um moderador agrega tarefas adicionais ao seu uso normal do Stack Overflow. Duas possíveis consequências são:
>
>    1. Diminuição no tempo despendido em perguntas e respostas para dar conta das tarefas de moderador.
>    2. Aumento do tempo total despendido no site, com subsequente desgaste e diminuição geral na participação do site.
>
> O que você acha mais provável de acontecer com você, por quê e como você pretende lidar com isto?

O mais próximo é o item 2, em especial a primeira frase. A segunda parte provavelmente não vai me afetar tanto, pois eu adoro isso aqui e já faço um bocado de trabalho de moderação com as ferramentas de usuário. Como moderador eu passaria finalmente a fazer uma série de contribuições que já tenho vontade, mas hoje não tenho motivação por falta de ferramentas mais adequadas.

> 4. Porque é que você se candidatou a moderador?

Em parte, porque algumas pessoas me convenceram. Em outra ocasião, eu até [já havia sido recomendado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/716/101). Eu demorei para decidir, mas me candidatei por ter certeza de que posso exercer o cargo com todo entusiasmo e dedicação, e concluí que é uma boa hora.

Outro motivo é que eu acho que a moderação precisa de mais diversidade. Me lembro do Gabe citar que a moderação ideal deveria ter 3 perfis distintos. Acho que hoje o time está homogêneo demais, e posso fazer a diferença abordando aspectos pouco explorados no SOpt.

Entendo que posso colaborar, como já demonstrei no passado, fazendo muita faxina no site. Algumas vezes senti uma certa dificuldade por sempre ter que pedir aos moderadores para que fizessem coisas que eu não podia como usuário. Ficava um "telefone sem fio". Fica muito melhor se eu puder assumir essa responsabilidade, ainda mais que eu gosto de fazer até as partes "chatas" da moderação. Também, de acordo com a [resposta do bfavaretto do ano passado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3958/101), as ferramentas ajudam muito entender melhor a comunidade.

Além disso, há muitos horários em que o site fica sem moderação, e eu estou online. Quero preencher essa lacuna.

Servirá como um desafio pessoal para lidar melhor com a comunidade, e talvez eu até surpreenda as poucas pessoas que não acreditam em mim.

Finalmente acho que posso liderar alguns movimentos necessários para evolução do site. Claro, posso fazer isso sem ser moderador, como já o fiz diversas vezes no passado, mas com a legitimidade dada pela comunidade, meu alcance para ajudar o site seria bem maior.

> 5. Qual é o conjunto de tags que você visita com mais frequência e quais os tipos de perguntas que você está mais propenso e capacitado a responder?

[Pode ser visto no meu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown?tab=tags). Acho que minha atuação é bem ampla e vem a calhar, já que o perfil dos moderadores atuais e possíveis novos moderadores são muito centrados em tecnologias mais específicas, notadamente JS, PHP, HTML, MySQL, Java, e coisas correlatas. Além de ter um conhecimento razoável nessas *tags*, ainda domino e/ou tenho pelo menos um conhecimento básico de C#, C, C++, Python, Ruby, VB.Net, Lua, conceitos de computação em geral (incluindo OOP, engenharia de software, etc.), vários bancos de dados, ferramentas em geral, só para citar algumas coisas. Sou ouro até em *string* :P ... Mas não sei nada sobre R :(

Em sendo moderador, pretendo aumentar a visitação em várias outras *tags*, hoje fico mais nas que respondo com frequência, e em perguntas que chamam a atenção pelo tema ou texto, seja ele muito bom ou muito ruim.

> 6. Qual/quais soft skills¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>    ¹soft skills: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas

Não vou negar que este não é o meu ponto forte, mas quero lembrar que uma das funções prioritárias do moderador é burocrática, usando ferramentas para melhorar a organização e bom andamento do site, sem qualquer interação humana direta. Agora, é claro que se eu trabalhar melhor o diálogo, farei um trabalho melhor nos dois aspectos.

Como usuário, sempre preferi defender com "unhas e dentes" o que entendi correto, independente de "ser político" para agradar as pessoas. Por outro lado, sempre atuei do jeito que achei que seria mais correto e justo.

Tenho plena consciência de que como moderador, é preciso mudar algumas atitudes. Tenho que estar preparado para não perder a linha nem quando provocado. Não deixarei de ter opiniões, nem de tomar atitudes, mas continuarei (sim eu já comecei) exercitando o "não precisa falar nada aqui" ou "dá pra ser macio aqui". Se eleito eu terei um diamante ao lado do nome, portanto não estarei mais falando só por mim.

Mas se eu não estiver seguro com algo, também é simples: deixarei outro moderador interagir, afinal, pessoas com *soft skills* temos de sobra atualmente no site, e trabalhar em equipe pressupõe que cada um coloque mais foco nas tarefas em que é melhor. Eu provavelmente terei um foco maior na "faxina". O simples fato de eu tirar parte do fardo "mecânico" dos demais moderadores, já permitirá que eles atendam melhor os usuários.

Além disso, eu tenho estado presente no chat cada vez mais, mesmo antes de se falar em novas eleições. Isto pode ajudar muito a recorrer à comunidade para ter uma segunda opinião em situações que eu não me sinta confortável para decidir algo sozinho.

Sei que posso falhar, portanto quanto mais importante a ação, mais pretendo conhecer a opinião de outras pessoas antes de agir. Se não estivesse consciente de que iria lidar com isso numa boa, eu nem me candidataria.

> 7. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Ficar no discurso de que ajuda usuários inexperientes qualquer um pode fazer (será que foi feito tudo o que foi dito nas eleições do ano passado?). Sou um dos usuários que mais analisa a fila de “primeiras perguntas”. Só não ajudo com tudo porque simplesmente não dá. Tenho que confiar que a comunidade fará o grosso do trabalho, deixando uma parcela para mim. Entendo que outros moderadores fazem e continuarão fazendo suas partes também.

Grande parte das minhas respostas é para usuários que estão iniciando, e tento sempre ser o mais abrangente possível, indicando na resposta como ele pode usar melhor o SOpt, com links e orientações. Tendo a responder até o que ele não perguntou diretamente, mas que vai ajudá-lo. Adoraria dizer que esse estilo é criação minha, mas copiei - sem a mesma competência - do [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert).

Me identifico com a [excelente resposta do ano passado do bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3958/101), essencialmente é isso, o resto é obviedade.

Claro que as necessidades podem mudar, então a forma de se fazer as coisas pode ter que mudar também. A ajuda de todos é fundamental para sempre se chegar na forma mais adequada de agir. E posso instruir os demais a fazerem o que for consenso.

Por parte dos usuários, não vejo nenhuma obrigação de ajudar a comunidade. Mas ser moderador me parece um pouco diferente. Oficialmente não tem regra alguma que obrigue ninguém a fazer nada, e nem farei nada tão frequente assim, mas me sinto na obrigação pessoal de dar uma atenção extra ao site.

Infelizmente, mesmo como moderador não poderei fazer algumas coisas que ajudariam muito a receber melhor os novatos. Tem coisa que é do próprio sistema.

> 8. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Não vejo um "grande problema", e sim coisas pontuais que podem ser melhoradas. Por exemplo, a comunidade poderia ser orientada para entender um pouco mais do funcionamento do site. Não é fácil, mas dá para trabalhar isso paulatinamente.

Apesar de achar que o moderador entra quando a comunidade falha, ele tem que ser atuante. Acho que moderador tem que liderar. Tem que ouvir a comunidade, estar junto dela o tempo todo. Talvez nesse aspecto eu já vá demonstrar alguma diferença. Tem que ter "tesão" pelo que está fazendo, mesmo quando o trabalho é essencialmente burocrático. Tem que propor inovações para a comunidade. Eu fiz muito isso e após as eleições anteriores fui deixando de fazer para dar espaço para os moderadores. Agora quero ser moderador para voltar a agitar o "pedaço". Só que mais moderado. Com a responsabilidade do cargo, mas com votos me suportando. É outra coisa. Moderador não pode criar transtorno, mas deve propor mudanças quando elas são necessárias.

Não farei grande revolução. Nem cabe. Mas conversarei sobre o que pode ser melhor para todos. Claro que em cada ponto alguns serão contra, mas o que vai importar é o consenso, não unanimidade. Como já dizia Nelson Rodrigues "toda unanimidade é burra".

Eu já estava para propor uma discussão sobre o escopo do site ([falei disso com o Gabe no chat há um tempo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30562951#30562951)) e ia postar na semana passada quando surgiu o assunto de eu me candidatar, então achei que era melhor esperar para não parecer campanha. Pretendo fazê-lo, eleito ou não.

Vou focar em coisas que podem trazer bons resultados, sem ficar inventando moda.

> 9. Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?

#### Zelar

O primário, que pode ser visto na [teoria da moderação](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), é ser um zelador. É arrumar a "confusão", cuidando do que a comunidade não alcança, mas em favor dela, seguindo os princípios e regras da rede e do site.

- Analisar o site como um todo só dá sendo moderador (detectar anomalias, entender a comunidade, resgatar o que passou despercebido). Há bem mais ferramentas de "manipulação de conteúdo", inclusive algumas que nunca percebi estarem sendo usadas aqui, mas que vejo em outros sites. Por exemplo: se não houver um bom motivo para não fazer, acho que *merge* de perguntas cai bem e elimina conteúdo duplicado, "alertas" e destaques em alguns posts também é interessante, e muitas vezes isto pode salvá-los;
- organizar *tags* erradas, prevenir seu mau uso, acertar sinônimos etc;
- bloquear o que está gerando confusão, e até fechar logo alguma coisa obviamente ruim que precisa de uma ação rápida, principalmente em horário que o fluxo de usuários é pequeno. Mas não esperem que eu tenha atuação exagerada nesse sentido, pois sempre que possível sem prejuízo, deixarei a comunidade agir por conta própria;
- desfazer ações *obviamente* erradas feitas por usuários;
- analisar o quanto antes as sinalizações, evitando que a origem se torne um problema. Exemplos: remover *spam*; converter "respostas" em comentários úteis antes que elas simplesmente sejam removidas (tem muita informação boa que é jogada fora só porque não é resposta).
- limpar comentários obsoletos é outra coisa importante. Já sinalizei muitos, mas noto que é um fardo que os moderadores nem sempre dão conta e talvez nem gostem muito pelo tempo que toma. Eu podendo fazer diretamente, não desvio o foco de outro moderador;
- pretendo usar as ferramentas "normais" de moderação como exemplo, mostrando como se faz, para que outras pessoas aprendam também. Conforme já [dito pelo Gabe no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11910?m=30562841#30562841), muitas pessoas não agem da melhor forma porque não sabem como.

Tem outras coisas que eu só vou perceber sendo moderador, mesmo ja tendo sido em outro site da rede. As ferramentas eram mais rudimentares, e a comunidade um pouco diferente;

#### Liderar

Talvez o mais importante seja liderar. Quem é líder, lidera. Quem não é, fica só na tentativa ou precisa impor. Claro que não é preciso ser moderador para liderar, e também já vimos que um diamante do lado do nome por si só não faz as pessoas seguirem cegamente o que for dito.

Um líder pega a bandeira que está passando e também levanta novas, esperando que outros a agarrem - mas ele larga a bandeira que as pessoas não querem levantada. Um líder não pode ser teimoso, e definitivamente não age por uma agenda própria. Um líder é firme, mas escuta. Um líder age em nome de todos, não em nome de sua visão íntima do que é bom para os outros

Um líder não é mole, não procura agradar a todos em detrimento do que é certo, não é unânime, mas não é autoritário em hipótese alguma. Um líder debate, discorda, opina, e pode até ser duro, mas não faz só o que bem entende, não vai contra tudo e contra todos.

Tem que dar os exemplos certos, que as pessoas olhem e enxerguem como adequados. Um líder não é cego. Um líder é questionador, acima de tudo.

A legitimidade talvez seja mais importante do que as ferramentas. "Quem é esse cara pra me dizer alguma coisa?" - "O moderador, e eu confio nele".

> 10. Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?

Já falei sobre a responsabilidade do diamante ao lado do nome na resposta 6. Sobre como me sinto, é difícil falar antes de acontecer (ao menos na nossa comunidade), mas posso especular que não vai mudar muito o meu modo de me "sentir" em relação ao SOpt. Tenho orgulho do meu conteúdo e de como a comunidade me trata no geral. Se tiver alguma coisa que eu acho que não condiz com um moderador eu vou lá e apago (afinal produzi muita coisa, sempre pode ter escapado alguma coisa, e já vi acontecer com outros).

Se houver alguma coisa que incomoda, ou uma sugestão de melhoria, basta que avisem. Na rede Stack Exchange é tão simples, não? Tudo pode ser avaliado, votado, corrigido e melhorado. Neste ponto, o SOpt já nasceu excelente.

Comment: Procurei ser autêntico, em vez de simplesmente dizer o que as pessoas gostariam de ler para me dar o voto. Não faz o meu estilo vender ilusão. Fico à disposição para responder dúvidas aqui ou no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43148/eleicao-sopt-2016). Aproveito para agradecer a imensa quantidade de votos que me confiaram nas primárias. Eu esperava uma rejeição maior, já que atuei de forma muito intensa, e isso atrai alguns opositores.

Comment: Tive uma rejeição percentual semelhante à do bfavaretto e Math ano passado e razoavelmente abaixo de outros candidatos. Só fiquei acima do Sergio, entre os eleitos, que curiosamente teve menos aprovação que os demais, e hoje também mostra um excelente trabalho. Aos que me veem com desconfiança, como já disse, estou à disposição para uma conversa franca e aberta. Eu sempre dei valor para a comunidade, a grande mudança será eu colocar a comunidade à frente dos meus interesses pessoais, como o "cargo" requer.

Comment: Excelente resposta. Apenas acho que o item 3 ficou redigido de uma forma meio confusa.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado. Você diz a pergunta ou a resposta? Eu achei a pergunta confusa, me pareceu contraditória. Fiquei meio sem saber o que responder direito.

Comment: Bem na verdade quanto ao item 3, sim a pergunta é um tanto confusa também. Mas ela basicamente está dizendo que moderar toma tempo e que isso pode também reduzir a participação dos moderadores no papel de usuários normais que fazem perguntas e respostas, e pede como é que você lidaria com isso. Essa pergunta foi elaborada provavelmente para barrar aqueles caras que acham que 5 minutos por semana é o suficiente para moderar ou que não tem tempo para nada e querem ainda mais uma responsabilidade ou aqueles que acessam o site uma vez por mês e querem ser moderadores.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é possível. Eu fiquei com o item 2, mas a primeira frase fala em aumentar o tempo dispendido no site, depois termina concluindo que isso irá diminuir a participação no site. Eu vou aumentar o tempo e aumentar a participação geral. Na verdade não sei se vou aumentar o tempo de fato, eu só agirei mais, no tempo que já estou no site procurando o que fazer :)

Comment: É que um usuário normal que acessa o site ocasionalmente e acaba virando moderador vai ou precisar usar o site ainda mais para poder se dedicar a função ou então subtrair parte do tempo que ele estaria perguntando e respondendo para poder moderar. A ideia é saber se o usuário continuaria sendo um usuário ativo ao tornar-se moderador ou não. Mas uma vez que você não é um usuário normal, e sim um robô com um programa de inteligência artifical avançada ativo 24x7 e que usa o SO-pt como um meio para tentar dominar o mundo, essa questão provavelmente não é um problema para você. :D

Comment: Clarificando #3.2 (minha pergunta): é comum para vários moderadores da rede aumentar a participação após a eleição por algum período, porém algum dia eles acabam se desgastando e diminuindo a participação. É algo que pode ser psicológico ou causado por fatores internos e externos (prioridades vão mudando ao longo, mudança de emprego, etc.). A questão psicológica é explicada porque cada um tem um balanço natural no empenho que coloca em certa atividade. A partir do momento em que você se força acima desse limite, o desgaste é inevitável, sem contar o fim da empolgação inicial.

Comment: Muito bem @bigown, aqui se vê bem o quão preparado estás para ser moderador. Mas isso qualquer pessoa atenta já sabia desde há muito tempo. O único ponto mais controverso seria o 6, mas já vimos que estás no caminho certo.

Comment: Sei que não tem nada a ver, mas acho que muita gente pode ter a mesma dúvida que eu, porque deixaste de ser moderador no [Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @utluiz aí eu não sei sobre outros, não sei se foi uma experiência pessoal, o tempo que eu fui moderador, é verdade que foi pouco tempo, fui igual o tempo. Minha suposição é que eu teria um pico inicial porque vai ter uma empolgação exagerada e depois chegar no patamar mais normal, além de que nem sempre terá um monte de coisa para fazer. O que eu sei é que não vou fazer tudo o que tem que fazer, se for eleito não serei o único moderador. Além disso se eu tiver compromissos, e tem algumas situações que me exigem um pouco mais, diminuirei a participação pontualmente...

Comment: ... se eu for pro Rio semana que vem, nem vou pensar em SOpt :P EU acho que minha dedicação no site não diminuiu, até acho que aumentou do passado pra cá. Só diminui o uso da moderação por algumas razões, vi algumas coisas era enxugar gelo e estava fazendo quase sozinho; ficar analisando toda hora "coisa falsa" estava enchendo a paciência e algumas coisas não são facilmente feitas por um usuário normal. Eu vou empolgar um pouco no início e talvez faça um pouco mais do que devia, até porque vejo que tem muita pra fazer, mas depois manterei o equilíbrio.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu sei ser o que precisar ser, claro que não virarei uma flor da noite pro dia, mas sei o que preciso fazer, não estou cego em relação a isso e tenho recursos. Não digo que será fácil, mas é algo possível que já venho fazendo. É uma pena que nem sempre é fácil ver que isso já está ocorrendo. Acabou o *pro tempore* :) Eu não me candidatei porque não achei que meu inglês era suficiente para ser moderador, além do que pouco antes da eleição peguei um projeto que exigiu minha dedicação por um tempo, como já ocorreu aqui. Tem momentos que é melhor não ter distração.

Comment: Sinceramente, e sem estar a ser politicamente correto, acho que deves ser eleito, és o utilizador mais ativo no site e com mais experiência em moderação(mesmo sem o diamante). Alias, mesmo para quem não te conhece basta ver as tuas estatísticas no site, são qualquer coisa.

Comment: @JorgeB. então empatou :P Obrigado.

Comment: Duas coisas que você focou e que acho muito importantes(não que as outras não o sejam): *"organizar tags erradas, prevenir seu mau uso, acertar sinônimos etc;"* e *"analisar o quanto antes as sinalizações ......."*.

Comment: Pelo que me é dado a aperceber, pela sua participação no site, você é uma pessoa extremamente competitiva(veja-se a primeira parte do seu 2º comentário). Você está preparado para, como moderador, refrear esse seu espírito competitivo?

Comment: @ramaral Este é um site de gamificação, a competitividade faz ele ser o que é. Sei que algumas pessoas não se preocupam tanto com isso, mas vários usuários se preocupam e eu entendo bem como isso funciona. Estou disposto a mudar. Não vou dizer que vou mudar muito, mas sei que como moderador não posso passar o exemplo errado. Tenho que ser mais leve em algumas coisas. Se algo te incomoda, estou aberto pra ouvir, pode me falar publicamente (aqui, no chat, ou se preferir em particular nas redes sociais mais conhecidas). Conto com seu suporte para me mostrar onde estou errando. Quero acertar.

Comment: @ramaral muitas vezes falta *feedback*. Note que no mesmo comentário já mostro essa disposição. Claro que não vou me anular como usuário. Acho que sei a medida do que preciso mudar e a medida do que preciso manter o que é o meu forte. Se eu for uma pessoa completamente diferente as pessoas estarão votando em algo falso.

Comment: Não me entenda mal. Eu louvo o seu espírito competitivo e não tenho nada a lhe apontar enquanto usuário. Julgo, no entanto, que concorda comigo que ser moderador impõe um tipo de actuação diferente em alguns aspectos.

Comment: @ramaral concordo 100%, tentei colocar no texto que entendo isso e preciso mudar algumas coisas. Como moderador a atuação tem que ser outra e como usuário preciso mudar também porque em certa medida não dá para dissociar os dois. Não posso nem "deixar pra lá" qualquer coisa, afinal isso não é o que um bom moderador faria, mas tenho que deixar pra lá várias coisas em nome do exemplo e polidez. Não nego que isso não é do meu feitio, mas sei que isso será necessário como moderador. Tenho que achar o equilíbrio de moderar com leveza e principalmente, para todos. Sei que terei menos liberdade.

Comment: Tenho a certeza que conseguirá encontrar esse equilíbrio.

Comment: Achei as respostas boas, você sempre escreve bastante, é sério, várias respostas do SOpt são enormes. Minha dúvida é se você escreve sem olhar para o teclado ou digita olhando?

Comment: @Orion eu sou o maior "cata milho", então tenho que olhar pro teclado. Não há meio de eu aprender digitar direito, por isso acabo errando muito e tenho que ficar consertando. Essa eu dei uma boa revisada, pedi para verem pra mim se tinha algo errado antes de postar :) Só isso? Obrigado.

Answer (score 15):

## Jorge B.

> 1. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Produzir diversas boas respostas é ótimo claro, mas é muito mais importante manter o site em ordem. Num caso destes falaria com o usuário de forma a tentar fazê-lo ver que o site é um site feito para nós e por nós, mas que o respeito e a cordialidade são a base do sucesso do site.
Se essa abordagem não resultasse falaria com os outros moderadores e CM's para discutir a possibilidade de alguma punição ou outro que meio que pudesse resolver o assunto.

> 2. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

A primeira coisa que eu faria era falar com o moderador em causa e saber quais as suas motivações e debater o assunto. Caso não se resolvesse o assunto poderia-se abrir uma pergunta no meta para saber a opinião da comunidade.

> 3. É fato conhecido que um moderador agrega tarefas adicionais ao seu uso normal do Stack Overflow. Duas possíveis consequências são:
>
>    1. Diminuição no tempo despendido em perguntas e respostas para dar conta das tarefas de moderador.
>    2. Aumento do tempo total despendido no site, com subsequente desgaste e diminuição geral na participação do site.
>
>    O que você acha mais provável de acontecer com você, por quê e como você pretende lidar com isto?

A verdade é que eu sempre me apaixonei mais por moderar do que por perguntar e responder. Quem me conhece sabe que é exactamente assim, não quer dizer que eu não vá fazendo umas perguntas e respondendo sempre que posso, mas é certo que prefiro fazer tarefas de moderação. Por isso, acho que não teria qualquer problema com essas *consequências*.

> 4. Porque é que você se candidatou a moderador?

Eu candidatei-me a moderador, depois de pensar muito bem, porque acho que posso ser uma mais valia para ajudar os actuais moderadores nas tarefas de moderação.
Já tenho um ano de experiência como [moderador pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore) no site da rede [Portuguese Language](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com), sou bastante participativo no meta, nas discussões sobre o nosso site e também no chat.
Quem me conhece sabe que sou bastante sensato e moderado no meu discurso e tento sempre resolver os problemas duma forma cordial e assertiva.

E é por esses motivos que acho que posso ser uma mais valia para o site e foi por isso que me decidi candidatar.

> 5. Qual é o conjunto de tags que você visita com mais frequência e quais os tipos de perguntas que você está mais propenso e capacitado a responder?

As tags que eu mais visito são PHP, MySQL, Android, Java, HTML e CSS. Eu gosto de responder a todo o tipo de perguntas, mas PHP e Android são a minha especialidade, por isso gosto de responder a todo o tipo de perguntas dessas áreas.

> 6. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>      <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

Acho que meio que respondi a isso na pergunta 4... Os que me conhecem, por aqui, sabem que tento ser sempre calmo e ponderado mesmo quando me atacam. Sou bastante participativo no chat e gosto de me dar bem com toda a gente. Acho que sou bastante sociável.

> 7. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

A melhor forma de interagir com um usuário novo no site é ser sempre simpático tentar guiar o usuário pelo caminho certo para que possam melhorar a qualidade das suas perguntas. Deixar um comentário ou até editar uma pergunta e avisar o usuário que é assim que ele deve proceder. Mesmo que ele seja rude, acho que solução é ser cordial e tentar fazer ver ao usuário que as regras do site têm a sua razão de ser e, caso seja necessário, que nos devemos respeitar uns aos outros, tanto aqui como em toda a nossa vida.

> 8. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Acho que um dos pontos mais importantes a serem discutidos no site é a qualidade das perguntas que tem vindo a diminuir. Independentemente, de ser eleito ou não, devíamos fazer um debate sobre o assunto e tentar perceber se isto é realmente um problema. No caso de ser um problema o que é que podemos vir a fazer para melhorar.

Sinceramente não quero ser *diferente* de nenhum dos moderadores actuais em nenhum ponto porque os actuais moderadores são muito bons no seu papel. Atenção, não pensem que vou dizer amém a tudo o que os outros moderadores acharem, apenas quero dizer com isto que os actuais moderadores são muito bons e que, se eu for eleito, que seja no mínimo tão bom como eles.

> 9. Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?

Os moderadores, para além das tarefas de moderação, devem ser os representantes do site perante os CM´s e a própria rede SE. Devem ser a *voz do povo* para que a SE(Stack Exchange) saiba o que pensam os nosso utilizadores sobre os assuntos mais pertinentes. Devem ser uma ponte, um facilitador entre os utilizadores e a SE.

Já nas tarefas de moderação o principal papel de um moderador, aqui no site, é tentar passar o mais "despercebido" possível. Tentar resolver todos os problemas que possam surgir tentado ser sempre o mais idóneo possível e estar atento para que problemas pequenos não se transformem em bola de neve.

> 10. Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?

Sinceramente, eu entendo que o diamante possa levar as pessoas a ver o utilizador de outra forma mas eu sempre achei que é o mesmo utilizador de antes.

O diamante traz responsabilidade e sempre que um moderador escreve alguma coisa pode ter uma repercussão diferente. Mas a verdade é que o conteúdo produzido por um moderador não é melhor nem pior só porque tem o diamante. Já se sabe que, por vezes, um moderador tem de manter algum distanciamento e lembrar-se que agora que tem o diamante deve ser um exemplo para os outros.

Comment: Não me quis alongar muito com grandes textos, acho que ser simples também é uma virtude, Se alguém tiver alguma pergunta ou dúvida pode colocar nos comentários.

Comment: Não sei se é possível ser moderador em mais de um site da rede, mas se for, caso sejas eleito aqui, vais recandidatar-te a moderador da "Portuguese Language"?

Comment: @ramaral É possível ser moderador em quantos sites da rede você quiser, desde que seja indicado ou eleito para tal e tenha tempo para moderar a todos de forma adequada. Já vi gente por aqui no SE que é moderador em até 3 sites da rede ao mesmo tempo e não duvido que exista ou já tenha existido alguém com 4 ou 5.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Obrigado. Não tinha a certeza se era possível, daí a ressalva, pois a pergunta não faria sentido caso não fosse. A razão da minha pergunta tem haver com essa sua frase: "... tenha tempo para moderá-los de forma adequada.".

Comment: @ramaral não posso garantir com certeza, mas em principio sim, se for eleito aqui também me candidatarei ao Portuguese Language. E sim, se me candidatei aqui é porque acho que tenho tempo para os dois sites. Ponderei bem sobre isso antes de me candidatar.

Comment: @ramaral Essa foi a [primeira pergunta (de forma diferente, creio eu)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/2?tab=nomination#comment-294850) que fiz ao Jorge B. Apenas postei aqui pois acho que as duas perguntas são relacionadas.

Comment: @Randrade Opa! Essa me escapou quando li lá os comentários.

Answer (score 14):

## rray

> 1. Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Conversaria com ele e tentaria orienta-lo sobre não criar atritos desnecessários. Reforçaria alguns pontos para uma boa participação do site como o [be nice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice); não levar os comentários como ofensa (ou adotar uma postura defensiva) geralmente quem comenta tenta ajudar de alguma forma; sugerir uma escrita mais branda nos comentários ou respostas uma vez que certas frases ou brincadeiras podem ser interpretadas de forma errada.

> 2. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Conversaria e explicaria melhor o meu ponto de vista e quais motivos/fatos/ideias fizeram eu chegar em uma conclusão diferente da dele(s), citaria outros casos iguais/parecidos que aconteceram e quais foram as conclusões.

> 3. É fato conhecido que um moderador agrega tarefas adicionais ao seu uso normal do Stack Overflow. Duas possíveis consequências são:
>
>    1. Diminuição no tempo despendido em perguntas e respostas para dar conta das tarefas de moderador.
>    2. Aumento do tempo total despendido no site, com subsequente desgaste e diminuição geral na participação do site.
>
> O que você acha mais provável de acontecer com você, por quê e como você pretende lidar com isto?

Hoje como usuário comum faço uma meta de analises(indepente da fila) por exemplo fazer pelo menos 10 por período (manhã, tarde, noite), caso eleito quero aplicar esse mesmo método. A primeira opção parece mais provável, a solução para equilibrar isso é ser mais seletivo na hora de fazer perguntas/repostas.

> 4. Porque é que você se candidatou a moderador?

Passo boooa parte do dia no site contribuindo(respondendo, fazendo análises etc) da forma que posso, é algo que me agrada muito.
Com esse entusiasmo quero ajudar a comunidade a resolver os problemas, discutir situações do site etc.
O sopt faz parte do meu dia e o eu puder fazer para melhora-lo quero fazer!

> 5. Qual é o conjunto de tags que você visita com mais frequência e quais os tipos de perguntas que você está mais propenso e capacitado a responder?

As tagas PHP, Javascript, banco de dados(MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server), terminologia e assuntos gerais sobre computação.

> 6. Qual/quais *soft skills*¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?
>      <sup>¹*soft skills*: conjunto de atributos e/ou competências que promovem boas relações com as pessoas</sup>

Paciência, proatividade para ajudar os usuários, boas habilidades de advinhação, (ser) firme em algumas situações e empatia.

> 7. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Normalmente deixo um comentário com links(tour, central de ajuda ou perguntas do meta) informativos de como o site funciona, pois é muito importante saber que o site não é um fórum, que é possíve editar o conteúdo e como formatá-lo. Caso ele já tenha essa conhecimento coloco mais comentários como: quais abordagem tentou para resolver o problema, tem alguma mensagem de erro? qual é o resultado esperado? e claro se tem alguma pergunta relacionado ao assunto eu deixo o link.

> 8. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

Um problema que vejo é na fila de edições, onde algumas são aprovadas sem a devida analise. O primeiro passo é orientar os usuários sobre o que deve ser aprovado(quando e quais caracteristicas fazem de uma edição boa ou ruim) ou não e dar um puxão de orelha quando precisar.

> 9. Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?

Os moderadores são guardiões da comunidade, estão atentos aos acontecimentos do site para tomar as devidas atitudes seja para resolver conflitos ou lidar com troll, vampiros ou seres mitologicos;
organizar (juntar) o conteúdo através de retagging ou adicionado uma lista de perguntas duplicadas. 
Com certeza a principal tarefa do moderador é lidar adequadamente com conflintos, ter o discernimento e a percepção para resolver o problema, caracteristicas
que nenhum algoritimo tem por mais inteligente que seja, por isso necessário uma humano, o moderador.

> 10. Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?

Não vejo o simbolo de diamante como um peso, ao interagir com os usuários utilizo um termo neutro, é claro que existe uma responsabilidade maior no que se escreve.

Comment: Parabéns @rray, tenho acompanhado seu trabalho aqui no stack e vejo que vc não é um 'caçador de pontos' apenas respondendo para ganhar ranking e sim se esforçando em passar o conhecimento, ajudando o próximo, teve meu voto..

Answer (score 12):

### JBueno

> **Nota**: Primeiramente desculpem a demora em responder, como este post veio ao ar justo no final de semana que eu não acessei o site (por questões pessoais) eu acabei vendo-o apenas hoje.

---

> **1.** Como você lidaria com um usuário que produz diversas boas respostas, mas que tende a causar discussões e receber sinalizações nos comentários?

Primeiramente, verificaria se há motivos para exclusão dos comentários (casos de comentários não construtivos ou rudes/abusivos. Caso isso prosseguisse, tentaria alertar o usuário, obviamente por algum chat privado ou o mecanismo que os moderadores têm para mandar mensagens.

Em últimos em caso, se houver reincidência do usuário, advertência pelo mecanismo do próprio site.

Mesmo que seja um usuário que possa fornecer boas respostas, todos devemos manter uma relação, respeitar as regras do site e acima de tudo [ser respeitoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

> **2**. Como você agiria se você discordasse do fechamento/remoção/etc de uma pergunta, por parte de outro moderador?

Exatamente como ajo atualmente (com qualquer usuário, no caso), tentaria entender quais os motivos que levaram o outro moderador a excluir a pergunta e expôr os porquês de eu achar que a pergunta merece continuar aberta.

> **3.** É fato conhecido que um moderador agrega tarefas adicionais ao seu uso normal do Stack Overflow. Duas possíveis consequências são:
>
> 1. Diminuição no tempo despendido em perguntas e respostas para dar conta das tarefas de moderador.
> 2. Aumento do tempo total despendido no site, com subsequente desgaste e diminuição geral na participação do site.
>
> O que você acha mais provável de acontecer com você, por quê e como você pretende lidar com isto?

Boa parte das minhas respostas, hoje, são dedicadas pro pessoal que tem dúvidas mais simples. Isso se deve a diversos motivos, primeiramente porque passo um bom tempo editando, comentando, avaliando publicações e no chat. Também porque dois grandes usuários do site são frequentes nas tags que domino.

Por isso, acho que nenhum dos dois tende a acontecer.

> **4**. Porque é que você se candidatou a moderador?

Primeiramente porque (no momento que decidi me candidatar) eu achei que seria uma das duas melhores entre todos os candidatos, por todo o conhecimento que tenho sobre as regras do site, por ser um usuário ativo, paciente e, principalmente, bem dedicado a manter o site organizado.

> **5**. Qual é o conjunto de tags que você visita com mais frequência e quais os tipos de perguntas que você está mais propenso e capacitado a responder?

[c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), [winforms](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) e [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Isso depende um pouco do contexto, mas, num geral, estou mais propenso a responder dúvidas relacionadas a erros, problemas com lógica e algumas do gênero.

> **6**. Qual/quais soft skills¹ você possui que são fundamentais para um moderador do SOPt?

Sou calmo, me comunico facilmente, sou atento e costumo sempre abstrair de mim as decisões que tomo em prol de um grupo.

> **7**. Todos os dias chegam novos usuários no site postando perguntas. Como são inexperientes, muitas destas perguntas têm problemas e acabam fechadas e/ou recebendo votos contrários. Que tipo de atitudes você costuma ou pretende tomar com novos usuários que enquanto bem-intencionados, postam perguntas de má qualidade?

Comentar, comentar, comentar. Como diria o Chris: "comentários hoje, comentários amanhã, comentários sempre".

Brincadeiras a parte, pra mim o mecanismo de comentários é de extrema importância, principalmente nestes casos. Tentar explicar pro usuário como o site funciona, apontando links da Central de Ajuda, do Tour, MCVE e qualquer outro que possa ajudá-lo a entender o funcionamento do site ou como melhorar suas perguntas.

> **8**. Na sua opinião, quais problemas que o StackOverflow tem que você pretende atuar para melhorar? Que ações você espera fazer em relação a isso? De que forma você pretende ser diferente dos demais moderadores nesse ponto?

O principal problema hoje é a falta de instrução para usuários novos que não sabem como o site funciona. Por muitas vezes, acabamos considerando os novos os usuários como se fossem veteranos e ao ver uma pergunta que não se encaixa nos padrões do site (porque está mal escrita, fora de escopo, ou não tem um MCVE), chovem downvotes e poucas (ou nenhuma) explicações são dadas.

> **9**. Na sua opinião, qual o papel dos moderadores?

Simples e direto. É prezar pelo bem do site.

> **10**. Se eleito, o diamante (símbolo dos moderadores) vai aparecer ao lado do seu nome em tudo que você já escreveu no site, sejam perguntas, respostas ou comentários. Tudo que você produziu no site passará a ser visto de outra maneira. Como você se sente em relação a isso?

Tranquilo. Desde que comecei a me familiarizar com o site, me esforço o máximo que posso para mantê-lo em ordem e sempre fui respeitoso.

Comment: Tentei não me delongar muito, (até dado momento) são postagens, com 10 perguntas cada, é bastante coisa pra quem se interessa em ler, não quero tornar mais cansativo. Quaisquer dúvidas, estou a disposição.